# Reference the current form in SQL select query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a query that I use on many forms to set the row source of a cascading combo box. I would ideally be able to copy/paste this set of combo boxes for use on multiple forms without having to edit the query. Is there a simple way to reference controls on the current form in a SQL select query?

My current query looks like this:

```
    SELECT tblExample.ChildID
    FROM tblExample
    WHERE ((tblExample.ParentID)=[Forms]![frmExample]![CboParentID]);
```

I want to create something more general, like:

```
    SELECT tblExample.ChildID
    FROM tblExample
    WHERE ((tblExample.ParentID)=Me![CboParentID]);
```

That way I don't have to edit [frmExample] every time I reuse this query.
Is it possible to reference controls on the current form in a general way?

Comment: Not that I know of. But you could create a function to be called when opening the form that sets the rowsource of the combobox.

Comment: Why would there be many forms for the same data input?

Comment: Access SQL queries lack the necessary context of where they are being called from to support such a reference.

Comment: @June7 Because there are a lot of one-to-many or many-to-many relationships in my data. The input is not the same, but the link to related tables is often the same.

Comment: If combobox is on same form as CboParentID, don't need full form reference prefix. SQL statement in RowSource can simply be: `SELECT ChildID FROM tblExample WHERE ParentID=[CboParentID];` Now copy/paste combobox.

Comment: Thanks @June7! That worked for me

Answer (score 1):

As a commenter suggested, because my parent combo box and child combo box appear together on forms, I can simplify my where condition to `WHERE ParentID=[CboParentID];`